# Help identifying a transformer with yellow bobbin and clarifying its purpose

Tags: transformer, identification

I've a small yellow taped transfomer. It has 6 terminals and one of the input and output terminals are shorted. It has a number (14) on one of the sides. I'd like to know the input and output terminals and also the use of this transformer.

[image: The six terminals of it]

[image: The number 14 on it]

Comment: What did it come out of? The pins are not "shorted" (zero resistance). There will be some resistance between them, that of the coil windings. You can see the wires connected to the pins on the top photo.

Comment: A mosquito bat used to taser mosquitos.When I tested with a multimeter it buzzed for a continuity test.

Comment: Try it on Ω range. You should find R > 0.

Comment: It rather looks like there are other thin wires to at least the centre pins.  Looks like a rudimentary step-up transformer similar to what you might find in a cheap camera flash unit to generate the 250V AC that is rectified to charge the flash capacitor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mosquito taser, here's a possible circuit solution:

[image]

Source: [this forum](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/i-bought-one-of-those-electronic-bug-zapper-fly-swatters-they-sort-of-work.138321/)

The transformer is used to make a high voltage from the 3 V supplied by the batteries. The transformer also provides feedback to the transistor so that it starts oscillating which is needed to make AC from the DC of the batteries. Transformers only work on AC so that's why that is needed.

Making the transformer part of the oscillation circuit also helps in cost saving (now only one transistor is needed) and also making sure maximum power is put through the transformer as it will saturate and that partly keeps the oscillation going.

These transformers usually do not have any part numbers, they're made for this purpose (bug zapper) only. They might even be made to order, the bug zapper manufacturer just tells the transformer factory what it needs and how many.

Comment: there's an npn transistor D882P.I have the PCB pictures but could'nt upload it.

Comment: Sure, a different transistor can be used as well. These kinds of circuits do not rely on a specific model transistor. I bet that it will work with 9 out of 10 NPN transistors. Also the circuit can be slightly different. The purpose of the transformer will still be the same though.

Comment: Can you explain me what exactly the transistor does there?

Comment: Not exactly as then you'd have to learn how a transistor works, that takes a couple of weeks to master ;-). But simplified, the transistor works as a switch, it connects and disconnects (on/off) the transformer to the battery. This makes the current through the transformer vary at the same rate. About 100 thousand times a second or thereabout. This constantly changing current creates a constantly changing magnetic field in the transformer and this creates the high voltage at the transformer's output.

Comment: Oh it's used as a switch.I know  little bit about transistors.thx again