# Simplest circuit for several hundred volts from 5v

Tags: voltage, converter, flash, camera

I am trying to make a simple camera flash circuit for a project, but I am really having a hard time. I can't seem to find a simple circuit anywhere. It doesn't need to maintain the high voltage under load, it just needs to charge a capacitor. I'm a journeyman electrician, but kind of a noob when it comes to electronics.

I built one using a 555 chip, but it could only output about 60 volts. I need about 200-300v. I feel like it can be a lot simpler too. I would appreciate some advice on what approach to use. I took apart a few cameras and they looked pretty simple with some tiny transformers and crystal oscillators, but I don't know the specs or what ones to buy. Maybe you could advise me on what a mini transformer or inductor is called and how to spec them for a circuit.

Thanks guys.

[image]

Comment: When the switch transistor opens, the supply voltage + inductor voltage will be across the transistor. 2N3904 is only rated for 40V CE. A dying transistor would surely limit the potential output voltage.

Comment: Just look at the circuit for any flash unit or emergency flasher (that uses a flash lamp.) These provide the circuit you want to copy. They can develop 300-400 V from a single 1.5 V battery.

Comment: i don't know if disposable cameras are still available anywhere, but those used to have a flash unit built in

Comment: Yeah, my problem is I need to create one myself. I found a really simple circuit for a camera flash but I can't figure out where to get the transformer now:                                       https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331614/help-identifying-a-transformer-with-yellow-bobbin-and-clarifying-its-purpose

Comment: Can any of you advise me on where to get a transformer that would work for a camera circuit?